# set div background color in body

Tags: html, css

Im trying to set the background color of a div tag that resides in a body tag to the entire screen but I have not found a satisfactory solution to this problem:

```
...
<body>
  <div>
  </div>
</body>
...
```

How can I set the background color of the whole page from the div tag that resides in body?

doing

```
div {
  background-color: green;
}
```

doesn't turn the background green.

Comment: Why aren't you setting the `body {background-color: xxx}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why can't you just set the body's background color?

Either way you'll have to do something like this:

CSS:

```
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100%; }

#fake_body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="fake_body"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unless I'm missing something, that should work. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/hfmLT/1/)

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hfmLT/ The only missing part is how to prevent the margin/padding across browsers...

Comment: Just updated with the margin/padding reset to 0px and added the updated fiddle, thanks for pointing that out Jared :)

Comment: Yes I know I can just set the background in a body tag, but not knowing something that should be possible pisses me off. And btw, about that margin part thing, usually you have to include a separate css called a "reset style sheet" for best cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Most people do include a reset, there's many out there too, but they all do the same. If you already have a reset included then most likely it would of already set the pages margin/padding to 0. Just try it with and without my padding/margin styles and see if you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the div covers the entire page I suppose.

```
#divID {
background-color: #fff;
top: 0;bottom: 0;right: 0;left: 0;
position: absolute;
}
```

Note:

Woah, 2011.. I guess I am late to the party.. by far. Anyways,  for the sake of google.